# SQL management studio create table error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am having trouble creating a new table, it gives me the error:
can anyone help me out, thanks!

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)

Here is the detailed log:

This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)

```
This backend version is not supported to design database diagrams or tables. (MS Visual Database Tools)
```

---

Program Location:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.DataTools.Interop.IDTTableDesignerFactory.NewTable(Object dsRef, Object pServiceProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.TableDesignerNode.CreateDesigner(IDTDocToolFactoryProvider factoryProvider, IVsDataConnection dataConnection)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDataDesignerNode.CreateDesigner()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDataDesignerNode.Open()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VirtualProject.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ISqlVirtualProject.CreateDesigner(Urn origUrn, DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, IManagedConnection con, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.ScriptFactory.CreateDesigner(DocumentType editorType, DocumentOptions aeOptions, Urn parentUrn, IManagedConnection mc, String fileName)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.VSIntegration.Editors.VsDocumentMenuItem.CreateDesignerWindow(IManagedConnection mc, DocumentOptions options)

Comment: Are you using the same version of Management Studio as the version of SQL Server that you are connecting to?

Comment: i am using ssms 2008, the database is just local

Answer (score 2):

That's a mismatch between the Management Studio version and the SQL Server version. Check that versions are compatible